# iText7- Pdf action controls are getting disappear after merge

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I have 2 fillable [PDF](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/jumpstart/browse/cmpfiles/chapter04/cmp_job_application.pdf). In both PDF data are different. When I merge those PDF into new PDF some action controllers get disappear.I am using itext 7.

```
PdfDocument destPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Template/cmp_job_application_new_mrg.pdf")));
PdfDocument[] sources = new PdfDocument[] {
         new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Template/cmp_job_application1.pdf"))),
            new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Template/cmp_job_application2.pdf"))) };
PdfPageFormCopier formCopier = new PdfPageFormCopier();
foreach (PdfDocument sourcePdfDocument in sources)
{
    sourcePdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(1,
        sourcePdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(), destPdfDocument, formCopier);
    sourcePdfDocument.Close();
}
destPdfDocument.Close();
```

Comment: You have linked one PDF document from iText Samples repository, while you say you have two PDF documents. Can you add the documents you are trying with?

Comment: @AlexeySubach Considering his code he appears to have used that single PDF twice. In the light of this his claim "In both PDF data are different." does not make sense...

Comment: I have two pdf first is original and second is copy of that but values in pdf are different. In first pdf full name is like 'Alexey' and in that second pdf full name is 'mkl'. When I merge those pdf into new pdf with name 'cmp_job_application_new_mrg.pdf' the check box of Native Language get disappear( they are not visible, but when I hover mouse on that position I can see hand ✋ mouse icon)

Comment: Ok, but are you saying when you merge the documents in this way the names like 'Alexey' and 'mkl' stay different in the merged result? It shouldn't be the case, the names should become same as well.

Comment: I am facing the same problem; did you figure it out?